# OptionsMenu stops appearing when navigate to other activity

Tags: android, tabactivity, android-optionsmenu

I have the following structure:

[image]

My problem is that whenever I go from **Activities** 1, 2 or 3 to **SubActivities** and back to the **Activities**, **Options Menu** stops appearing (Neither `onCreateOptionsMenu` nor `onPrepareOptionsMenu`). My guess is that this is because **Activities** are stopped when **SubActivities** are called, then **Activites** are not recreated (`onCreate` is not called) when I return to them.

Is there a way to force `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be called when Activity is resumed (in `onResume`)?

**Update**

I understand what's going on now. Problem is that **Options Menu** is called from `TabActivity`, not from the Activities under it. I need the `onCreateOptionsMenu`/`onPrepareOptionsMenu` of the **Activities** to run instead of `TabActivity`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. Problem is that **Options Menu** is called from `TabActivity`, not from the Activities under it. What I did was:

In my `TabActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    return getCurrentActivity().onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

And in the Activities:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Do my work in the Activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just call onCreateOptionsMenu in every activity i need it in seperatly then change the context for each activitys onCreateOptionsMenu seperatly to reflect the senario so when the activity is resumed so is its onCreateOptionsMenu.....hope that helps

Comment: And how do you get Menu object (`onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`)?

Answer (score 0):

I just use it in each activity I want to have menu options say if Im in activity 1 my menu options reflect activity 2,3 when I'm in activity 2 my menu options reflect 1,3 and so on but in each activity that has a menu you must put the code  in doing that when you change between activities you will always have a menu.....it works for me I don't know if its the best way but it works for me

Answer (score -1):

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

```
    menu.add (Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, (""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 3, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 4, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 5, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 6, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 7, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 8, Menu.NONE,(""));
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 9, Menu.NONE,(""));
    return true;
} // end onCreateOptionsMenu()

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:

            return true;
        case 1:

            return true;
        case 2:


          return true;
        case 3:



             return true;
        case 4:


            return true;
        case 5:




            return true;
        case 6:

           return true;
        case 7:




            return true;
        case 8:


            return true;
        case 9:



            return true;


    }
    return false;
}
```

is what i use...if this helps maybe check out my question "append.text at cursor in fragment"....im super desperate for help

Comment: Sorry, this does not add any new info. I can make the Options Menu appear the 1st time, problem when navigating outside the Activity